# Highcharts widget with text output that is based on data from Thingspeak

Tags: highcharts, widget

I have worked a while now with highcharts to visualize columns, lines based on data taken from measurements.

Now I am struggeling to find a way to show pre-defined "text" in a widget based on the input data.

Example:
rain intensity data from 0 to 0.1 --> text message should be "low rain",
rain intensity data will be 0.2 to 1.0 --> text message in the same widget shall change to "medium rain" etc.

Does anyone can give a hint how to solve this? **Again, I do not need a graph, bar chart, gauge .. just a text in a box that is displayed variable depending on the measurement data.** Thank you for any hint!

I have screened the web, but so far can only find label definition or text labels that are static attached to values within a chart.

Comment: Hi @Cooky, Do you want to show the text on a chart? If so, you are probably looking for something like annotations: https://www.highcharts.com/docs/advanced-chart-features/annotations-module If not, please add more information about your requirement.

Comment: Dear @ppotaczek -  Thank you very much for your answer. In such examples, the annotations or labels are fixed as input (correct?), but not dynamic depending on values. To explain my idea, I have attached the PDF that desribes my intended widget for text only. Thank you for co-creation ;-)

Comment: Sorry PDF does not work - text only: 
**** works to display data in a chart like gauge ***

$.getJSON('https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/xxxxx/fields/field1/last.json?api_key=U1LKJ99C01TA3UQY', function(data) {

console.log(data)      var point = chartSpeed.series[0].points[0]      point.update(parseFloat(data.field1));

 What works: Up to now I get here a  float value like 0.5

Based on this data call text messages shall be shown in a widget:

If (point.update < 0.1) {
 Text variable_1 = „low rain“
}

If (point.update > 0.1 and < 0.5) {
 Text_variable_1 = „medium rain“
}

Comment: @ppotaczek - Now I have come a bit closer: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/n3L08h96/ this fiddle contains custom text for a colum. I have  changed the code in the fiddle and managed to toggle the text depending on 1 or 0 als Wert. But seems not correct, as I need it based on the data range. Any idea? (see next part)

Comment: Highcharts.chart('container', {
  chart: {
    type: 'column'
  },
  plotOptions: {
    column: {
      dataLabels: {
        enabled: true,
        verticalAlign: 'top',
        align: 'center',
        formatter() {
         Wert = 0;
          if (Wert) {
            return 'My custom text that can be very long'
          } else {
            return 'My text can short'
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  
  

  series: [{
    data: [0]
  }]
});

Answer (score 0):

You can format your data labels depending on the `y` value. For example:

```
  plotOptions: {
    bar: {
      dataLabels: {
        ...,
        formatter() {
          if (this.y <= 0.1) {
            return 'low rain';
          } else if (this.y <= 1) {
            return 'medium rain';
          } else {
            return 'heavy rain';
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/yxq6dcLk/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/plotOptions.bar.dataLabels.formatter

Comment: So great hint .. by co-insidence and  a long night ;-) I have found my own starting point with formatter https://jsfiddle.net/f70axkx0/ and have modified it in the way you are describing above. As a consequence, my own created widget  is now running with live data and the chart shows after changing plot options, colors, ... only text depending on the live data. Thank you very much again. Anybody in need for a similar solution please contact me - I can share it. Greetings!  I / we can close this chat.